# login class returning bol(false)

Tags: php

I have the fallowing class that I have written for a login application using this [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/understanding-hash-functions-and-keeping-passwords-safe/) :

```
class passHash{

    private static $algo='$2y$';
    private static $cost ='12$';

    private function generateSalt(){
       $salt=substr(sha1(mt_rand()),0,22);
       return $salt;
    }

    public function hashPassword($password){
       $hashpassword=crypt($password,self::$algo.self::$cost.self::generateSalt());
       return $hashpassword;
    }

    public function checkPassword($hash, $password){
        $fullsalt=substr($hash,0,29);
        $newhash=crypt($password,$fullsalt);

        if ($newhash==$password){
           return true;
        }else{
           return false;
       }

   }
}
```

I think the code is self explanatory and i saw that there are a lot of questions regarding this login class.
Now the problem that i have encountered is with checking the password. If I do something like:

```
$a=passHash::hashPassword('1234');

$b=passHash::checkPassword($a,'1234');
var_dump($b);
```

I gate the result of bool(false)

Where is the problem with this code ?

---

**EDIT 1**
if I modifay the checkPassword like this:

```
public function checkPassword($hash, $password){
    $fullsalt=substr($hash,0,29);
    $newhash=crypt($password,$fullsalt).'<br>';
    return $newhash;
}
```

and then i do :

```
$a=passHash::hashPassword('1234');
echo 'hashPassword: '.$a.'<br>';

$b=passHash::checkPassword($a,'1234');
echo 'checkPassword: '.$b.'<br>';
```

i get
hashPassword:$2y$12$6e29c2bbdacad854b1a63O8aty2a/.MQN0wbdmClnhXMbH3/tfQfG
checkPassword: $2y$12$6e29c2bbdacad854b1a63O8aty2a/.MQN0wbdmClnhXMbH3/tfQfG

they are identical .. so where is the problem ?

Comment: just use http://php.net/password_hash functions instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: and don't do calls from incompatible context. Explicitly declare your functions as static if you want to use them statically!

Comment: in my test machine I use php.net/password_hash. but there are some other machines where i don't have the latest php (PHP 5 >= 5.5.0) ans so i'm forced to do something ...

Comment: look at the _see also_ part of the documentation page: ___[» userland implementation](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)___

Comment: thanks, I'll look into it. but I'm curios why the code above doesn't work

Comment: Maybe you should use `$newhash === $hash`?

Comment: tried that, same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test should be this:

```
    if ($newhash==$hash){
       return true;
    }else{
       return false;
   }
```

Comment: ...or better yet, `return ($newhash==$hash);`

Answer (score 0):

the full working code is:

```
class passHash{
    private static $algo='$2y$';
    private static $cost ='12$';

    private function generateSalt(){
        $salt=substr(sha1(mt_rand()),0,22);
        return $salt;
    }

    /**
    @param string $password
    */
    public function hashPassword($password){
        $hashpassword=crypt($password,self::$algo.self::$cost.self::generateSalt());
        return $hashpassword;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $hashpassword
     * @param string $password
     */
    public function checkPassword($hashpassword, $password){
        $fullsalt=substr($hashpassword,0,29);
        $newhash=crypt($password,$fullsalt);

        return ($newhash==$hashpassword);
   }
}
```